# Which background and theme fits a Razerclaw Shifter Ranger (Archer)

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger, background, theme

Our DM declared that as of Lv11 we will be allowed to choose a BG and Theme - as long as it matches our (still to be written) background story.

I am a LV10 Razorclaw DEX Ranger heading towards the Battlefield Archer Path. My story involves me being exiled from action taken during against an aggressive take over of our tribe. My character is also a devout of Selune.

- Sohei seems like a great choice due to it's bonus to Perception and Insight, gained from wandering the lands and helping the shrines and temples of Selune. 
  However it's encounter power only offers a minor 'melee' attack, is this minute enough to overlook?

As for the other, I am leaning towards "Occupation - Hunter" for the pure +2 Perception bonus seeing as 1) I am the only Perc trained char 2) it is befitting of a hunter/ranger to see what others overlook

Or are there other options that fit a wandering nomad?
(I have taken wasteland wanderer as lv.1 feat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlaw goes great with Ranger, and it is quite powerful.

The encounter power of Outlaw requires a weapon at-will attack power, which you should be using anyway (Twin Strike), and combat advantage that you have from frost cheese. The daze is only good of course if you do not kill the target on your first turn.
Also it is easy to explain in the background.

A Seer is a bit harder, but the Perception reroll might be worth it.

Unfortunately most of the themes provide bonuses for melee combatants only, so you do not have a big selection.

If you do not need access to a specific Skill that a Background could provide, I suggest you take `Trained from Birth for a Specific Prophecy`. One of the strongest backgrounds. If your DM does not like it, take anything that gives +2 to Perception tests, like Goblin Foe.

Comment: OUtlaw definetly looks like it has some good synergy and adds some pre-defined flavor to my char. What Background would you suggest?

Comment: @ExoWaltz if no backgrounds are prohibited then Auspicious Birth/Born under a Bad Sign is a good one, though a bit wasted on a ranged ranger.

Comment: If your DM uses Skill challenges, +2 to an untrained skill which you have a decent ability bonus to may also be a good option for a background.